# How to disable checkbox "Enable multiple check-out" for new projects?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010.
When I created a new project in the Team Project Settings> Source Control checkbox "Enable multiple check-out" on by default.
How to disable checkbox "Enable multiple check-out" for new projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your Process Template.
At first, download it locally by selecting in VS "Team" > "Team Project Collection Settings" > "Process Template Manager...", then click on your template & select Download. This will send all the files on you local PC.
Now open the local file "..\VersionControl\VersionControl.xml" and change entry `<exclusive_checkout required="false" />` into `true`.
Return to "Team" > "Team Project Collection Settings" > "Process Template Manager..." and now select Upload.
Once this is done any new Team Project you generate will have this option "Enable multiple check-out" unset by default.

Comment: I did this and now users are overwriting others changes?  So do you need to check Get Latest upon checkin?  I also dont get notified if someone has a file currently checked out...very odd