# How to change default settings for source control in TFS?

Tags: tfs, multiple-checkout

In my TFS server when ever I create a Team Project my default settings for **Multiple Checkout** is enabled and for **Get latest on check-out** is disabled. I want to set these to **Multiple Checkout: disabled** and **Get latest on check-out: enabled**.

How can I change default settings for source control in TFS server 2013?

[image: My Default Settings]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that it's any different to how it's done for [2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519495/how-to-disable-checkbox-enable-multiple-check-out-for-new-projects)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't think so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519495/how-to-disable-checkbox-enable-multiple-check-out-for-new-projects):

> You need to edit your Process Template.
>
> At first, download it locally by selecting in VS "Team" > "Team
>   Project Collection Settings" > "Process Template Manager...", then
>   click on your template & select Download. This will send all the files
>   on you local PC.
>
> Now open the local file "..\VersionControl\VersionControl.xml" and
>   change entry  into true.
>
> Return to "Team" > "Team Project Collection Settings" > "Process
>   Template Manager..." and now select Upload.
>
> Once this is done any new Team Project you generate will have this
>   option "Enable multiple check-out" unset by default.

tnx to @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

As has been the case since 2005 you can customise this in the Process Template.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243831.aspx

You can create a custom process template with these settings and create new team projects with it.